# Copy/Paste Cell to Filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I am currently having an issue with a VBA code which i am unable to make it work. My idea was to have 2 sheets, the first sheet is with just a cell (Cell C7) to enter a customer code with a button "Click Here". The 2nd sheet (name: Volume) is a Pivot of all Data that is related to the customer codes (Volume, Net sale, Patterns, etc...). I wish to have a rule that can copy the number (customer code) that can be type in, and past to the 2nd sheet in the filter pivot field area (Cell A1), automatically it will filter and show the necessary data of that customer code.
I've tried to do a Macro Recording, but it ended up fix on one Customer code only (see below):

```
Range("C7"). Select
Activesheet.pivotTables("Volume").PivotFields("Customer Code").ClearAllFilters
Activesheet.pivotTables("Volume").PivotFields("Customer Code").CurrentPage ="0001101073"
ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

As you can see the number of customer code is fix, so if i do type in another different number, it will automatically still filter the number that the Macro recorded.

I've then tried to change it, by putting everything in the same sheet, so the type in customer code cell is E3 and the pivot field filter cell is C3 by using this rule, but it still doesn't work (see below):

```
Sub Filter_Click()
    If Range("E3").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You must enter the customer code.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Volume").PivotFields("customer code").ClearAllFilters
         ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Volume").PivotFields("customer code").PivotFilters , Add:=xlValueEquals, Value1:=Range("C3").Value
    End With  
End Sub
```

I appreciate the kind help. Thank you so much.Regards.

Comment: What is wrong selecting the customer in the pivot table itself?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there with your two attempts. Combining them gets you even closer. However you're using the value of C3, not E3 (where I think the code should be)

Try the following:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Volume").PivotFields("customer code")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = Range("e3").Value
End With
```

UPDATE:

If you want to error trap in the event of an invalid customer code being chosen - use this:

```
Sub Filter_Click()
    If Range("E3").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You must enter the customer code.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Volume").PivotFields("customer code")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .CurrentPage = Range("E3").Value
    End With
    If Err = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Customer code not valid"
    Else
        Err.Raise Err
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your fast reply, i tried out and it shows me Error execution '1004'. Here is my full code: If Range("E3").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You must enter the customer code.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Volume").PivotFields("customer code")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = Range("e3").Value
    End With

Comment: Is the value in E3 (the customer code) present in the filter list of the pivot? Probably not if it's erroring. I've updated my answer to aid with that possibility.

Comment: I've just re-read your question and I note that the customer code is entered by the user into `C7`. If that's still the case, then you'll need to alter the two `E3`'s in my answer to `C7`

Comment: Hi, It doesn't show error anymore, but it doesn't function, the customer code from E3 doesn't copy to C7, so the filter doesn't function. Please help. thank you so much

Comment: Where is the user entering the customer code? `E3` or `C7`?

Comment: The user enter the customer code in E3. And C7 is the pivot field to filter.

Comment: Are you getting the "Customer code not valid" error? Is the code being entered definitely in the list?

Comment: At the beginning, it did shows 'customer code not valid', but then after 2 tries, it stops and it just doesn't filter even if i change different customer codes. The customer code i copy and paste from the Raw data of the Pivot to make sure it matches, but it still doesn't work, even entered manually too.

Comment: I must admit, I'm struggling to understand the issue now. I've created a mock-up myself and tested the code and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Perhaps i should try to recreate a brand new one, because i've been testing so many VBA on this one. It doesn't mention at all that there is an error with the VBA, it functions but it just doesn't filter weirdly. I will keep you posted. Thank you sooo much for your kind help.

Comment: Hi, i tried to recreated it, but it still doesn't function. At the beginning it asked me to continue to enter the customer code, while i have already. After couple of tries, it stop but doesn't filter

Comment: I've realised the code doesn't error if it's not the usual issue so I've tweaked it to error properly.

Comment: Hello, it works! thank you so much. I was wondering as well, is there a way to add in that if there is no customer code, then the pivot table below will not show any information?